# Compiling a c application that links to a static library on AIX

Tags: c, gcc, aix, static-linking, .a

I'm trying to compile my application to link to a static library (.a file)

The command I use to build is this:

```
gcc -DUNIX -maix32 -o Release/bin/testApp Release/obj/main.o -ltestLib
```

When I build I get the following errors:

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .test
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

Where test is a method in libtestLib.a

Also if I try and build with a dynamic lib then it is successful.

```
gcc -DUNIX -maix32 -o Release/bin/testApp Release/obj/main.o libtestLib.so
```

Can you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: why dont you try the options (-bloadmap or -bnoquiet) mentioned, or perhaps post the source code?

Comment: It doesn't recognise those options when I try them.

Comment: Note that if you want to pass those options to the linker on the `gcc` command line, you'll probably need to use `-Wl,-bloadmap` or `-Wl,-bnoquiet`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try specifying a path to the archive file, rather than `-ltestLib`?

```
gcc -DUNIX -maix32 /path/to/testLib.a -o Release/bin/testApp Release/obj/main.o
```

Comment: Yes this sadly this fails in the same way

Comment: Maybe run ``dump -g testLib.a`` to verify the symbol is present